# Wordpress Advanced Custom Fields Array to List Wrapped in HTML

Tags: arrays, foreach, field

I am using wordpress + advanced custom fields

I have a multiple selection checkbox for items from 1-10.

I need to have it so the return array will show a list of the items in bold and with breaks.

**Custom field name:** article-name

```
<?php foreach(the_field('article-name') as $article) {
echo '<strong>'.$article.'</strong><br />';
} ?>
```

It displays the array, then gives me an invalid argument warning. **What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: Can you show some more of your code?

Comment: That's basically all that I have. I just want the array to display as a list...

Answer (score 0):

You are using the_field function which actually prints the value.

Use get_field instead to assign each value to the variable `$article`, see below:

```
<?php foreach(get_field('article-name') as $article) {
echo '<strong>'.$article.'</strong><br />';
} ?>
```

Comment: Just noticed that I responded to a more than 1 year old question. :)